# Given a linear function T determine whether $T(1,1)=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given a linear function $T$ such that $T(1,0) = 1$ and $T(0,1) = 0$ then determine whether is $T(1,1) = 1$ .

The given conditions are forming a basis matrix \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} and if we form a linear equation Ax=b in two variables we can get the constants value as $1$ and $0$.

Based on it $ax+by$ linear equation can be calculated on values of $x$ and $y$ as $1$ and $1$ respectively so am getting the condition as true.

Is $T(1,1) = 1$ and is this a correct approach to solve it?

Comment: $$T(1,1)=T[(1,0)+(0,1)]=T(1,0)+T(0,1)=1+0=1$$

Comment: @ChinnapparajR can we find coefficients a and b of linear function ax+by by plugging in x and y values respectively and then find T(1,1) based on a and b?

Comment: @TenDoeschate: Yes, but that is a detour. (You should get $T(x,y)=x$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Got it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T$ is a linear transform, $T(x+y) = T(x)+T(y)$ for all vectors $x$ and $y$.

Also, $(1,0) + (0,1) = (1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $T$ can be represented with a $(1\times2)$-dimensional matrix.

Let this associated matrix be $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \end{pmatrix}$.

Then $T(1,0) \equiv  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^T = a$.

Similarly, $T(0,1) \equiv  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T = b$.

Therefore it must be the case that a=1, b=0.

So $T(1,1) \equiv  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T = 1$.

Comment: @H Park Thanks for the detailed explanation